# Cycle and Edit Through XML Children Based On Values

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have an interface to cycle through XML child and edit them. Something like this:

[image: XML]

The XML file looks as such:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
       <query id="bk100">
          <question>Do we have Docker security?</question>
          <answer>Yes</answer>
          <comment>None</comment>
          <genre>Cloud</genre>
       </query>
       <query id="bk101">
          <question>Do we have cloud security</question>
          <answer>Yes</answer>
          <comment>None</comment>
          <genre>SCPC</genre>
       </query>
       <query id="bk100">
          <question>Do we have Kubernetos security?</question>
          <answer>Yes</answer>
          <comment>None</comment>
          <genre>Cloud</genre>
       </query>
    </catalog>
```

I am reading and storing the children as such in `Global variabes`:

```
xmlUrl = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Blah.xml"
oXMLFile.Load (xmlUrl)
Set QuestionNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/query/question/text()")
```

Now once the user selects a `Genre` from the intrface (using a combobox or whatever), for example `SCPC` - I want the next and previous buttons to allow the to just loop through the questions and answers (and edit them) in the  `Genre SCPC`

so for example, a Pseudo-implementation for the ``Next button` would look like:

```
'Next XML Node Iterartor
Private Sub btnNextEntry_Click()
   Interate Where GenreNodes(i).NodeValue = "SCPC"
        txtQuestion.Value = QuestionNodes(i).NodeValue
        Pause 'When the user clicks Next again, the Next Node Data Is Showed
End Sub
```

and similarly something for the `Previous button`. Obviously I am out of logic here how to achieve this. As I also need to have editing and save functionality, I thought it was good idea to use index based iteration, but with the `Genre` based filtering, it doesn't make a lot of sense now and I am stuck.

Any tips ideas how I can handle this? Thanks.

Comment: Create a functon which returns a collection of genre-specific nodes from your global `QuestionNodes`, then use the buttons to navigate over that filtered collection.  Also, separate out the UI interface for editing into  `LoadNode` and `SaveNode` methods - then you have single points of contact between your nodes and the user interface, which you can call from your other methods.

Comment: @TimWilliams I am confused on how to do this, what should be the data types and implementation for save? Any pointers? What I was planning to use the `<query id="bk100">` id property as a primary key and then use a collection to store all `ids`  for a specific genre, but I realized that will be super slow. Also big problem will be when I try to implement the save feature :(

Comment: @TimWilliams about `LoadNode` and `SaveNode` UI separation -  can you go into a bit more detail? I am unable to understand this.

Comment: `LoadNode` is passed a node and populates the userform textboxes with the node's child element values.  `SaveNode` does the reverse.

Comment: @TimWilliams Can you please give some pseudo code? To pass data between forms I am generally using a temporary file. This would really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Set QuestionNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/query/question/text()")` for the question list makes it more difficult to filter than it needs to be. It's easier to use a list of the query nodes and then access the child nodes as required.

So, if you wanted to list all of the nodes then use:

```
Dim queryNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
' ...
Set queryNodes = oXmlFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/query")
```

and you could then work with the values of the child nodes like this:

```
Dim node As IXMLDOMNode

For Each node In queryNodes
    Debug.Print "Q: " & node.SelectSingleNode("question").Text & vbCrLf & _
        "A: " & node.SelectSingleNode("answer").Text & vbCrLf & _
        "C: " & node.SelectSingleNode("comment").Text & vbCrLf & _
        "G: " & node.SelectSingleNode("genre").Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
Next node
```

If you then wanted to only work with nodes where the genre is "SCPC" then, it's just a case of changing the `queryNodes` list, like this:

```
Set queryNodes = oXmlFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/query[genre='SCPC']")
```

The code to access the child nodes doesn't change just because we have filtered the list differently. All of the changes are contained in how we create the `queryNodes` list. The code to update `queryNodes` could be called from the event handler for the combobox that allows the user to choose a genre.

We could adapt the code for printing all of the node values into a sub which prints the values of a specific node (as suggested by Tim Williams in the comments):

```
Sub printNode(node As IXMLDOMNode)

Debug.Print "Q: " & node.SelectSingleNode("question").Text & vbCrLf & _
    "A: " & node.SelectSingleNode("answer").Text & vbCrLf & _
    "C: " & node.SelectSingleNode("comment").Text & vbCrLf & _
    "G: " & node.SelectSingleNode("genre").Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

End Sub
```

To control which node is displayed via your interface, use the `Item` property of the `queryNodes` list. The first node is `queryNodes.Item(0)`, the next is `queryNodes.Item(1)` and so on.

If we use a variable called `position` to keep track of where we are in the list then the Previous button in your interface should make `position = position - 1` and your Next button should make `position = position + 1`.

So, once the user presses Previous or Next, we would update `position` and then call `printNode queryNodes.Item(position)`. There is always the chance that we have gone beyond either the start or the end of the list and this can be checked with `If Not queryNodes.Item(position) Is Nothing` before we try to call `printNode`.

For your specific case, you would need a sub to populate the fields in your interface. To do this, rename `printNode` to `loadNode` and, instead of printing to the Debug window, copy the relevant text from each child node into the corresponding field in your interface.

A `saveNode` function would just be the reverse of that - copy the value of each field in your interface into the text property of the relevant child node

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for that. I realized my question was too complicated an wasn't expecting an answer this thorough.

Comment: For anyone interested, this is how you write it in code: `oXmlFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/query[genre='" & var_name & "']")`